# Is there a stone bin?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I recently found out that there's a stone pot that functions like a barrel. Is there, similarly, a stone substitute for bins? Or any other material that isn't wood or metal?

Comment: If I remember correctly, Masterwork DF adds stone bins.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there are no stone bins. Bins must be made out of wood or metal, barring strange moods producing bin-artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

And don't forget, you can also store almost anything in mine-carts! They are normally made out of metal, but you can also make them of wood. They [haul/hold more than any other container in the game](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Container) (8.3 times as a barrel or large pot, and 5 times as much as a wheelbarrow), and your dwarves are not slowed when pushing them, unlike the weight movement penalties they have when carrying containers or objects.